# Change back to old Lock-Screen Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, lock-screen

The new Unity lock-screen now crashed thrice at my system - completely locking me out as a result. Also unlocking the new lockscreen in terminal was not working, when it had already crashed. Being crashed meaning, having no password field and statusbar, just the wallpaper with dots on it, not reacting to anything at all.

How do I change back to the old lock-screen (or any other working lock-screen)? There was a possibility using compiz manager but it was removed in the last update... I know the old lock-screen is still there because if I lock my PC from a different terminal via commandline the old lockscreen is used. Using the same command on my desktop the new lock-screen is used so does not solve my problem - else I would just make a script...

Comment: Look at this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#What_to_do_if_things_go_wrong

Comment: @Xubu-Tur I've seen this howto before and it is too old... But thanks. GDM is not installed and installing will install whole gnome desktop and sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm does nothing at all...

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm` ?

Comment: @Xubu-Tur Now I did, but what is it supposed to change? There is still no config menu when reconfiguring, also still the new lock-screen.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem by installing gnome 3 and removing unity completely... Don't need an unstable desktop environment...